# What is texName in SurfaceTexture?

Tags: java, android

Actually i'm trying to take photo without showing preview. For that i came up with SurfaceTexture but i want to know what is texName in surface texture and for what purpose it is used?

```
//c is camera instance
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);
c.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
```

what is `10` in surface texture?

Answer (score 0):

10 is txtName an int value 
which is  the OpenGL texture object name (e.g. generated via glGenTextures)
refer this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture

Comment: Actually i referred doc but i didn't get enough information. Can you explain briefly please. Is that like variable name and can we give whatever value we want ,what  will be the impact due to that?